# Exchange 2013 RegEx transport rule

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2013, regex, regular-expressions

I am looking to create some transport rules for outgoing email based upon AD properties.

eg. Phone: 123-456-7890

Where the actual inserted code looks like "Phone: %%PhoneNumber%%", retrieving the phone number from AD.  That part works fine.

Setting up my transport rule, I include the following conditions:
[image: Conditions]

However, that condition doesn't work.  I've tried it without the single-quotes, without the preceding ^.   Really, all I want is for the rule to make sure that %%PhoneNumber%% is not empty.

Anyone know how to make Exchange do that?

Comment: Are you waiting for replication before testing the rule? "Replication time between Active Directory domain controllers varies depending on the number of sites in the organization, slow links, and other factors outside the control of Exchange. When you configure transport rules in your organization, make sure that you consider replication delays." From: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351127(v=exchg.150).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I eventually realized that it was the Chrome web browser not being compatible with ECP.  Using IE or PowerShell works.

FYI:  I used "\w." (without the double-quotes) for that rule.